# Django returning None after request.POST.get

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I'm new to Django and AJAX and I'm trying to send the ID of a dropdown list to the Django View with an ajax POST. This ID is then used in a queryset filter to return with AJAX the row, based off the ID. I'm getting stuck with applying the filter to the query set, as it seems to be posting the ID and then a variable with None. When I print to console the variable sent in the POST I get the ID, followed by none, e.g.:

```
1748
None
```

My HTML is:

```
<select id="drugSet">
{% for dose in dose_set %}
<option id="{{ dose.pubmed_id }}">{{ dose.drug_name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
<span id="drugName"></span>
```

Javascript:

```
function NeedDrugInformation() {
            var elementID = document.getElementById("drugSet");
            var strUser = elementID.options[elementID.selectedIndex].id;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "drugsanddoses/",
                dataType: "text",
                async: true,
                data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}', drugID: strUser },
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "drugsanddoses",
                dataType: "text",
                async: true,
                data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' },
                success: function (json) {
                    $('#drugName').html(json.drugInfo);
                    // $('.ajaxProgress').hide();
                }
            })
        }
```

views.py:

```
def drugsanddoses(request):

    drugIdentifier = request.POST.get('drugID')

    print(drugIdentifier)

    drugInfo = RiskCalculator.objects.values('drug_name', 'l_dose', 'h_dose', 'risk', 'pubmed_id', 'updated')

    response_data = {}

    try:
        response_data['drugInfo'] = str(drugInfo)
    except: 
        response_data['result'] = 'No details found'
        response_data['message'] = 'There is currently no information in the database for this drug.'


    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making two Ajax requests; one a POST, where the ID is present, and one a GET, where the ID is absent so it prints None. I don't really understand *why* you're making two requests, but that is what you are doing.

Comment: I want to send the ID to the view and have it return the associated row from the database. Can I do this with a single POST?

Comment: Yes, of course. You just need to define the `success` function on the `ajax` call that does the POST.